# Send Image Upload data to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, send

I want to send data to database so when user upload image all of his image data saves in database in mysql please tell me what should I do to make it work .

When User Upload image he can see this type of data after successful upload

```
Upload: wallpaper.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 8.7072027134876 kB
Stored in: upload/wallpaper.jpg
```

So I want to save this data in database like Type in type column, size in size column and similarly image link in link column

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$username = "root";
    $password = "123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("user", $dbhandle);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <= 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))




  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 10024) . " kB<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

**Here is HTML Code**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats your question? What error do you get?

Comment: You need to take the incoming datastream, probably want to base64 encode it, and then stored that inside a BLOB in the database.

Comment: A better way is to NOT store it in a BLOB, but a reference link TO the file that is stored. Things just get complicated that way if you do, and will increase your DB size considerably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add:

```
$link="upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$filesize=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblname` (`size`,`type`,`link`) VALUES ('$filesize','$filetype','$link')") or die(mysql_error());
```

After:

```
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Ofcourse you should get `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` initialized before you save your data. And surely you should have `size`,`type`,`link` columns present in your table

Comment: real obscure, my answer was downvoted and then accepted. anyway, thanks to author